# How to change transparency of "Xamarin.Forms Material Visual" disabled button?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, material-design, custom-renderer, materialbutton

I would like to change the transparency level of disabled button.

[image]

Disabled Button View

[image]

Enabled Button View

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LabelButton), typeof(SkyRacing.Droid.LabelButtonRenderer))]
namespace SkyRacing.Droid
{
    public class LabelButtonRenderer : MaterialButtonRenderer
    {
        public LabelButtonRenderer(Context ctx) : base(ctx)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            if (!Element.IsEnabled)
                Element.Opacity = 0.9;
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Xamarin.Forms.Button.IsEnabled))
            {
                if (!Element.IsEnabled)
                    Element.Opacity = 0.9;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried creating a custom renderer and changing the opacity of the disabled button to 0.9 but still it is too transparent. How can reduce the transparency level of the button? (fyi, on debug mode I've inspected the `Element` property. It is already 1 even before I set to 0.9, wonder how it is too much transparent).

Answer (score 4):

You can customize any property if `Button` when it is `disabled` by using `Style`.  Change the value of `Opacity` to change transparency level of the button.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="BaseButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger TargetType="Button"
                     Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#5019171c" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    <Button Text="sampleButton"  BackgroundColor="Blue" x:Name="sampleButton" Style="{StaticResource BaseButton}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Update code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(LabelButtonRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace App389.Droid
{
    public class LabelButtonRenderer : MaterialButtonRenderer
    {
        public LabelButtonRenderer(Context ctx) : base(ctx)
        {

        }


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Xamarin.Forms.Button.IsEnabled))
            {
                if (Element.IsEnabled == false) {
                                       
                    Control.BackgroundTintList = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.button_normalcolor);
                }
                else
                {
                    Control.BackgroundTintList = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.button_disablecolor);
                }
            }

        }       
    }
}
```

And add color in the colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
  
    <color name="button_normalcolor">#ff00</color>
    <color name="button_disablecolor">#FF4081</color>

</resources>
```

Update iOS code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(LabelButtonRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
public class LabelButtonRenderer : MaterialButtonRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName.ToString());

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Xamarin.Forms.Button.IsEnabled))
        {
            Control.BackgroundColor = Element.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried this, even though I set the opacity to 1, the button still transparent. For Default visual it's works ok, but for the Material visual they are applying something else for the transparent.

Comment: @DragonWarrior Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Hi @Jack Hua - MSFT, Sorry for the delayed reply. I think you are probably close, but I don't want to hard code the background color there. All I want is, it should take whatever color I set in the XMAL code and remove the transparency if disabled. Thanks for your effort, I really really appreciate it.

Comment: `<Button BackgroundColor="Black" Visual="Material" Text="Click Me!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsEnabled="False"/>` You can check with this simple button. Remember, *Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material* needed to be installed to apply the material design effect.

Comment: Yes, use my code need to hardcode the color there because Control.BackgroundTintList uses colors in Resource.Color. Otherwise you can pass the color from forms project to Android project and get it in the custom renderer and use that color.

Comment: Instead of passing the color I can get the background color originally set to the element.
`Control.Background.SetTintList(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid()));` this should do the trick.

Comment: Can you add the iOS specific code too? so I can tick this answer ☑️. Thanks again!

Comment: @DragonWarrior I have updated the iOS specific code.

Comment: Nope, I've already tried `Control.BackgroundColor`, it didn't work

Comment: for Material Button?

Comment: Yes, Material Button.

Comment: That's strange, anyway I'll check this again

Comment: Yes, try again please.

Comment: Hua , nope it did not work, I've just checked still the button is transparent

Comment: What you want is change transparency of “Xamarin.Forms Material Visual” disabled button, right? So it should be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provide by @Jack is working for me. Additionally you can try like this :

```
<Button x:Name="testButton" Text="Test">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Button>
```

If this is also not working, then please share more details about your xaml

Comment: nope this didn't work for me, might work for Default visual but not for ```Visual="Material"```

Comment: please share your xaml details

Comment: `<Button BackgroundColor="Black" Visual="Material" Text="Click Me!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsEnabled="False"/>`

You can check with this simple button. Remember, *Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material* needed to be installed to apply the material design effect.